# Azure SSL certificate shows Guest User Error

Tags: azure, ssl, azure-keyvault

I have purchased an SSL cert for my site and the cert has three steps you need to do in order to have it fully configured. The first step is "Key Vault Status" which I then click on and it shows the following error:

> You do not have permission to get the service prinicipal information needed to assign a Key Vault to your certificate. Please login with an account which is either the owner of the subscription or an admin of the Active Directory to configure Key Vault settings.

This is very confusing because I am the owner of this subscription and I also went and created a new Key Vault just in case it was due to not having one created in the first place. In addition I checked the Access Control for this cert and I am also listed as Owner.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try to troubleshoot with this link:https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/dd34901d-9573-4b0a-ad52-e4fb47506c85/app-service-certificate-you-do-not-have-permission-to-get-the-service-prinicipal-information-needed

Comment: Check if `enable the access to arm for template deployment` from azure key vault-access policies-show advanced access policies.

Comment: Thanks - I checked both the box that @NancyXiong noted and the one in the MSDN issue submitted by Joy, to no avail. I've logged in and out several times. The certificate is in the "Pending Issuance" state. Any other guidance is appreciated.

Comment: so the error is disappearing? and the new issue is that `The certificate is in the "Pending Issuance" state. `. For this, you need to Verify certificate domain ownership in the second step.

Comment: @NancyXiong No the error is still there - I was just trying to provide information that was requested in the MSDN forum.

Comment: Yes, the error still very much exists. I think it appears when user is added as a guest user in the tenant and is irrespective of user's rights and permissions.Meaning, even if the guest user has been added to the role of subscription owner and have relevant rights on the key vault, the error would still appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I finally got to the bottom of it - I'll outline the story here as this was the solution but may not work for everyone.

- When I first created my Azure account I did so under `email address 1`
- A few years later I had migrated most of my email to `email address 2`. To get status updates and other things I transferred the subscription to `email address 2`.
- Every other service has worked fine accept for this SSL issue as well as not being able to buy a support plan (it popped open an email app to send to `email address 1`)

In speaking with the [AzureSupport](https://twitter.com/AzureSupport) twitter account they agreed that it was strange and arranged for a one time ticket for support.

The support agent asked me to check my Access Policies for the Key Vault I had created. This showed that `email 1` is indeed a user in the Azure Active Direction and they mentioned that I'd need to have the admin add it. Since I had noticed the irregularities with `email address 1` showing up in the URL and in the email for adding support I logged into Azure using `email address 1` and went to Azure Active Directory->Users under that account.

[image: Active directory showing two users, and one is Guest]

I then selected the guest account, selected Directory Role, and added a new role of Application Administrator. Now all of it is working as expected!

Answer (score 0):

My subscription was attached to employer Active Directory and I can't change my role in it.
I solve this problem by creating my own Active Directory and by moving subscription to this AD.